# converting image to all sizes on upload vs resizing on request via php

Tags: php, image-processing, image-resizing

So I have a platform for users which allows them to upload a fair amount of pictures. At the moment, I have my server resizing and saving all images individually to my **CDN** (so I can pick the best option in order to reduce load time when a user requests to view it), but it seems very wasteful in regards to server storage.

The images are being converted into resolutions of 1200px, 500px, 140px, 40px and 24px.

What I'm wondering is, would it be more efficient to just save the file at 1200px, then serve it via **PHP** at the requested size using something like `ImageMagick`? Would there be any major trade-offs and if so, is it worth it?

What I'm doing right now:

> https://v1x-3.hbcdn.net/user/filename-500x500.jpg

An example of what I could do:

> https://v1x-3.hbcdn.net/image.php?type=user&file=filename&resolution=500

Cheers.

Comment: Your proposal, like all performance optimizations, is a trade off.  Yes, you will save server space, but it will come at the expense of request time and cpu utilization as you would need to resize the image on each request.  You could reduce this cost by only resizing the image on demand if you dont have one cached on the file-system already.  Generally speaking, server disk space is basically free so you should have a good reason to optimize for size in that regard.

Comment: Good question I must admit but this sounds opinion-based and localized. Do see the answer though, it's worth a read.

Comment: You can use Imagemagick to resize and save to all the sizes you want in one read of the image in one command line. See parenthesis processing in command line at https://imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#write. You could write a script that would then process each image upon upload

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it's not, because:

1. you have a small number of sizes
2. if you will not use caching (image generation on first request only) you can DDOS yourself (image processing its a cpu affected process)
3. have to do extra work if will use CDN like Cloudflare for HTTP-caching

It makes sense if you have a lot sizes of images, for example, API that supports multiple Andoid/IOS devices, meaning iphone 3 supports 320x320 image only and if you dont have users with such device, your server never creates such image.

Advice:

During image generation, use [optimization](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/imagick.setcompressionquality.php) it reduces image size with imperceptible loss of quality.

Comment: This. On-demand resizing is a great way to change the F5 button from "Refresh" to "DoS".